# Making 5 random changes to an adjacency list for a directed graph

Tags: python, numpy, networkx, gephi

Is there an automated way to delete 5 edges from an existing adjacency list, while at the same time adding 5 new random edges that connect existing nodes to the list? Meaning that the deleted edges will be replaced by random edges.

Alternatively, I think it could also work if a program randomly deletes 5 edges from the list and saves that as a new file. Maybe, then, I could use a graph generator that creates random adjacency list with 5 edges that must be made out of nodes ranging from 0-25 for instance.

What I am trying to archive:

I transformed a Causal Loop Diagram into a directed network, so that I can analyze some of its properties such as average path length and other centrality measures. The network comprises 26 nodes and 67 edges. Now that I analyzed all of the important features of the network, I would like to create 1000 slightly changed networks, so that I can check how robust the centrality measures are to random perturbations.

In other words, I would like to create 1000 mutated networks to analyze the changes in betweenness centrality (BC) and closeness centrality (CC) for each of the variables/nodes in the network.

Comment: Hi, and welcome.  Can you tell us a little bit more about what you're starting with and then what you're hoping to end up with?  If you start with a networkx graph in place, it won't be hard to write something that would delete 5 edges and generate 5 edges, but we need to understand a little better what you're starting from.

Comment: This might help ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I transformed a Causal Loop Diagram into a directed network, so that I can analyse some of its properties such as average path length and other centrality measures. This network comprises 26 nodes and 67 edges. Now that I analysed all of the important features of the network, I would like to create 1000 slightly changed networks, so that I can check how robust the centrality measures are to random perturbations.

Answer (score 0):

The method would be to create a list of the edges of `G` (a simple way is `L = list(G.edges())`.

Then choose 5 random edges from the list.  For that, use `random.sample` (which requires the random module).  `random.sample` is better than `random.choice` because you can control how many it chooses (note, it chooses 'without replacement').  So `edges_to_delete = random.sample(L, 5)`

Then choose 5 random pairs of edges to join.  If you want to be careful that they don't already exist do it in a for loop, selecting 2 random nodes and if they aren't joined, add them to the graph.

All told it looks like this:

```
import networkx as nx
import random
G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(100,0.1)
L = list(G.edges())
edges_to_delete = random.sample(L, 5)
G.remove_edges_from(edges_to_delete)

#it's probably better to create a copy of `G` rather than act on `G` directly.
node_list = list(G.nodes())
for counter in range(5):
    candidate_edge = tuple(random.sample(node_list,2))
    if not G.has_edge(*candidate_edge):
        G.add_edge(*candidate_edge)
```

note the `*` in the last two lines.  This is because the functions expect 2 arguments, but instead I'm passing a single tuple of length 2.  The `*` tells it to actually treat the entries in the tuple as the arguments of the function.